# How to use dejavu for elasticsearch on local running it from opensource.appbase.io

Tags: apache, ssl, elasticsearch

I wanted to use the wonderful dejavu software to audit a local elasticsearch instance.

Wondefull idea, but currently it looks that it's not easy as it should be. But I found a way to do it, and that's what I want to share with Community.

Basically you can run dejavu from the opensource.appbase.io but first you need to set SSL to access your local ES. Here is how I did it in less than 1 hour (saving you other 4 hours of googling/reasearch/try&fail).

This is little bit like issue https://github.com/appbaseio/dejavu/issues/106 but running it from the dejavu's website instead of local extension.

Just in case, I've tested this on Chrome and Firefox, both succesfully. I've done it all in Windows, but I suppose Linux should work because nothing described here is Windows-specific.

Bad news: the google extension fails (no idea because the error reporting does not exist)

More: I don't want to deal with Docker, that is the other "easy" way that is provided.

So this is what I did:

1.- here is the link to the main web site: https://opensource.appbase.io/dejavu/

2.- click to run it live. Here is the link: https://opensource.appbase.io/dejavu/live?default=true

It will start inmediately, but won't be able to get any data. Don't worry.

3.- point it to local, in my case was http://localhost:9200 plus my ES index document. Failed, but don't worry.

If you look at the console and network tools of your browser, dejavu looks to be trying SSL to connect with your ES. Here is where setting SSL on your ES (or in front of it) became required.

There are several ways to do this. In my case (because it was not for production) I've used Apache httpd, specifically the already packaged (portable) version of xampp, so it's just about minutes to have it downloaded and running. I donwloaded from here: https://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp

4.- after installed Apache, open a new tab in your browser and try the SSL like https://localhost and it will give you a correct warning about the certificate. Just trust on it to check SSL is up and running. Don't worry about the warning.

5.- to set the SSL to redirect ES requests correctly, here you have these simple settings to add in apache config file, then restart apache. I took the idea from here: [Elasticsearch with apache2 ssl proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943552/elasticsearch-with-apache2-ssl-proxy)

```
<Proxy http://127.0.0.1:9200>
    ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=90
</Proxy>
<LocationMatch "^(/_aliases|.*/_search|.*/_mapping|/_nodes|/_settings)$">
    ProxyPassMatch http://127.0.0.1:9200
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9200
</LocationMatch>
```

6.- now it is required to set the cross-origin authorization at your ES. Add these lines into your elasticsearch.yml file and restart ES. The instructions comes from dejavu's github site: https://github.com/appbaseio/dejavu

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "https://opensource.appbase.io"
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

7.- test how is it going: get your index mapping with something like this: https://localhost/your_es_doc_index/_mapping

You will get the JSON maping of your index. Everything is working (Apache and ES)

8.- now, in your dejavu, point it to https://localhost:443 (yes, the port must be set because if not it will assume to do https://localhost:9200, believe it or not). Don't forget to set your ES index document in the "header" box ni dejavu. Now click in "Connect".

After couple of seconds, you will have the list of your types ready and accesible in dejavu

Comment: Well, it's 28th Feb 2019 today, and the I tried the Google Chrome extension and it's working :D